# Large array iteration in NodeJS and Send Message

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am creating an API for my iOS Native App in NodeJS. I use SailsJS. I would like to get advise for creating a utility function for sending messages to 10000 users. Right now i am using a for loop to iterate through all the 8000 records and sending messges. I am not sure it is a right approach iterate through 8000 user at once. We need to send the message in 2 minutes to all the 8000 users. But right now it takes around 5 - 10 minutes send a message. I know NodeJS is a single threaded language and it can’t utilise more than 1 core.

We have a 4 core cloud server with 8GB Ram

1. Is there a better way to do this in less time.
2. What if I use a nodeJS console application to do this.
3. What If I use a Multithreaded language like Python, Ruby or Java for creating the console app to send message.
4. What If I use a framework like Django, Ruby on Rails
   to create another web-app just sending message.
5. Is it good and faster to fetch the entire 10000 records and store them in a Javascript Global variable array when I am having 8GB RAM.

Please advise. I want to make the message sending process faster and stable without making the server busy.

Comment: Hi, this'll add extra infrastructure, but I think it might be the best way to go. Why not add a redis instance and use the pub/sub functionality? You have your clients subscribe to a channel and from your node.js server you would publish whatever data you need to.

Comment: Push messages via Apple Push Notification Service or other kind of messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of job queues to delegate task for sending messages.

The rabbitMq has a good reputation on this kind of process.

You can install an instance of RabbitMQ on your server and assign workers to do the jobs.

To get started, you can read on http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html

It has an adapter available on node which you can also integrate with sails application.

https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp

I hope this helps you achieve the speed you need on your application.

Cheers.